# SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'explore.ratings.id'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

What I'm trying to do is selecting the trips , then group them by rate.

> note: ratings is a polymorphic relationship

given we have 2 models :

```
trips
  id => int
  price => float
  city_id => uint
........

ratings:
  id => int
  ratable_id => int
  ratable_type=> varchar
  rate => small-int
......
```

and here how am trying to do it:

```
\App\Models\Trip::where('price','>=','100')->with(['ratings' => function ($query) {
        $query->groupBy('ratings.rate');
    }])->get();
```

and `Whoops!`:

> "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1
>   of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated
>   column 'explore.ratings.id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select * from `ratings` where
>   `ratings`.`ratable_id` in (1, 2) and `ratings`.`ratable_type` =
>   App\Models\Trip group by `ratings`.`rate`)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid your answer wasn't what I was looking for, you didn't get what I was saying!

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid none solved my issue , that's why I'm trying to come-up with different solutions

Comment: Strange, For your issue this would help you in moving forward  [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: There can be multiple `ratings` per `trip`. Which one do you want to use for grouping?

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thank you, I'm already looking at it.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir all of them actually , the result should be something like  `[
    3 =>
    [
        trip,
        trip,
        trip,
    ],
    5 => [
        trip   
    ]
]` so I can loop on them based on the rating!

Answer (score 1):

Use a different approach:

```
$grouped = [];
$trips = \App\Models\Trip::where('price', '>=', '100')->with('ratings')->get();
foreach($trips as $trip) {
    foreach($trip->ratings as $rating) {
        $grouped[$rating->rate][] = $trip;
    }
}
```

Or use a JOIN:

```
$trips = \App\Models\Trip::select('trips.*', 'ratings.rate')
    ->join('ratings', 'ratings.ratable_id', 'trips.id')
    ->where('ratings.ratable_type', 'App\Models\Trip')
    ->where('trips.price', '>=', '100')
    ->get();
$grouped = $trips->groupBy('rate');
```

Comment: I'm avoiding this approach due to N1+ problem within the loop , the more trips , the more loops you will have to make, in order to collect it, it will be my last solution tho, if I couldn't do it in one go within `mysql` itself

Comment: Do you mean the N + 1 query problem?

Comment: not the query since it's eagerly loaded , but the loop itself , will be costly if there is lots of ratings , which in the long run it will be...

Comment: I added a different solution.

Answer (score -1):

in your config -> database.php set  'strict' => false,

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).